# Cant Update 12.04

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

When the update icon popped up, it said:

> An Error occurred, please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see whats wrong. The error message was:
>
> Error: Marking the upgrade (E:error,pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.) This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this from the command line to resolve unmet dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After running this you can now perform your upgrade easily.